# PhP - CloudConvert: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.

Tags: php, ssl, curl, cloudconvert

I'm trying to use [CloudConvert API](https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-php) in PhP and I'm getting the following [error](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html):

```
CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60)
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.
```

Reading their API source code I see that they use the GuzzleClient for requests. I guess if I just disable the SSL verification on cURL it would work. I just don't know how to do it globally. I know how to do it for the request: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`  but that doesn't help me since I don't have the control on how CloudConvert do their API requests.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I'm running my project using MAMP and macOS Sierra.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. As I told before the CloudConvert API can take a Guzzle client in the constructor, so I create the client and set the certificate to it:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => $this->config->application->sslDir . "cacert.pem" ]);
    $api = new Api("xxxxxxx", $client);

        $api->convert([
            'inputformat' => 'html',
            'outputformat' => 'docx',
            'input' => 'upload',
            'file' => fopen('/Users/andre/Projects/x/Quote.html', 'r'),
        ])
            ->wait()
            ->download('/Users/andre/Projects/x/Quote.docx');
```